# stdin 'hop' over process?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Is there a way that stdin can 'hop' over a process? For example, in the following command,

```
cat file | ssh host 'mkdir -p /some/directory && cat > /some/directory/file'
```

This will send the stdin from the first `cat` to `mkdir` and the second `cat` will recieve no stdin. I want the stdout from the first `cat` to hop over `mkdir` and only be sent to the second `cat`. I am aware that you can run something like:

```
cat file | ssh host 'cat > /tmp/file2 ; mkdir -p /some/directory && mv /tmp/file2 /some/directory/'
```

That only works when copying a file or

```
cat file | ssh host 'tee >(mkdir -p /some/directory) >/some/directory/file'
```

But that only works because the `mkdir` command does not use stdin. Is there a command that will execute a command that replicates this functionality? Something like:

```
cat file | ssh host 'stdinhop mkdir -p /some/directory | cat > /some/directory/file'
```

where `stdinhop` would not send its stdin to mkdir, but it redirect it to stdout so the second cat can read it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect the first command's stdin from `/dev/null`:

```
anthony@Watt:~$ echo -e 'hello\nworld' | ssh localhost 'cat < /dev/null && cat -n'
     1  hello
     2  world
```

The lines are numbered, so the 2<sup>nd</sup> `cat` got them.

If not using ssh in there, you'd use a subshell: `echo -e 'hello\nworld' | ( cat < /dev/null && cat -n )`

Comment: @don_crissti true, I figured OP wanted to run a command that insists on reading STDIN.

Comment: @don_crissti - exactly. But, essentially, the `{` grouping; `}` is already happening here. There's a single fork point - `ssh`. It kind of serves the same purpose here, but is a little more like `out | { { group; } ; { group; }; { group; }; }` and so it still needs protecting from the shell's i/o init for every group. In the same way you can absorb the input into a group like that, you can also skip it by being explicit about redirections - or both could work. You could skip over an interval group, maybe, by redirecting `/dev/null` into the group's stdin.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is already happening, actually. And certainly `mkdir` isn't your problem - it doesn't read `stdin` anyway. That pipe is inherited as stdin by all of the children of `ssh` - unless, that is, you are getting a pseudo terminal like `ssh -t`.

Barring that, then the problem is that the shell running those commands is one of `ssh`'s children - and part of its job is to open 0,1,2 for each command group it runs. Your input, then, is just getting lost in the shuffle because it is on a common descriptor - the same descriptor that the shell reopens for every one of its children.

And so most simply, I think, you can just move the input to a descriptor that is other than one of those three defaults. For example, the following works for me:

```
echo hey there >file
cat file | ssh mikeserv@localhost '
               exec 3<&0
               mkdir -p .
               echo ho there
               cat <&3'
```

If I run the above it prints:

```
ho there
hey there
```

You might also find some utility in the `-W` option to `ssh`. `man ssh` says:

- `-W` *host* *:port* - Requests that standard input and output on the client be forwarded to *host* on *port* over the secure channel. Implies `-N`, `-T`, `ExitOnForwardFailure` and `ClearAllForwardings`. ***Works with Protocol version 2 only***